# What does g { } mean in chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I often saw lowercase g or b,in the source or console window,what do these mean?
[image: g{}]
looks like some kind of type,but what type it is...
[image: The little g and b]

Answer (score 3):

This is typically an instance of an object defined with the following pattern, sometimes referred as the *Constructor pattern*:

```
// Car constructor
function Car (miles) {
    this.miles = miles;
}

// Instantiate the object without arguments
var car = new Car();
```

After minification of javascript, the `Car` function could be renamed to a variable like `g`. Thus, the debugger will show the value `g {}` for the instance of the car.

> What type it is ?

It should now be obvious that it depends of the script. In your case it seems to be a `VehicleActionChannel`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I asked so many people about this question, only you paid attention and answered spectifically.